# Need to store a file/pdf in SQLite in Ionic 4

Tags: sqlite, pdf, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I’m new to ionic and in my Ionic Application, I need to store a pdf and image file in SQLite i.e in the app storage and should open within app. I will get the file from another database like MongoDB in the URL format. Could anyone of you help me out of this and suggest any references to complete the app storage using SQLite.

Thanks in advance.

I have researched on different aspects but could not find any.

Comment: I think you can convert file in blob and you can store it in local db

Comment: Unless it's a small file, it's more common to just store the path to the file in the database and let the file system manage the actual file. But you'd store the contents of the file as a blob in the database.

Comment: @Shawn I will retrieve a file from another db i.e online storage

Comment: @PareshGami even for local SQL file I have set the blob type with the .pdf file but I'm unable to open the pdf in the application.-----> by declaring as file BLOB.

Comment: you can use file opener plugin to open pdf file https://ionicacademy.com/open-pdf-ionic-4/

Comment: @sunilkalwani we are able to open pdf using file opener in browser or any other pdf supported apps but we need to view the pdf in the designed ionic app only.

Comment: @geethika yerramsetti you can use InAppBrowser plugin for that